# pandas.Series.interpolate() along "index" shows unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, series

A `pandas.Series()` called "bla" in my example contains pressures in *Pa* as the index and wind speeds in *m/s* as values:

```
bla
100200.0    2.0
97600.0     NaN
91100.0     NaN
85000.0     3.0
82600.0     NaN
           ... 
6670.0      NaN
5000.0      2.0
4490.0      NaN
3880.0      NaN
3000.0      9.0
Length: 29498, dtype: float64

bla.index
Float64Index([100200.0,  97600.0,  91100.0,  85000.0,  82600.0,  81400.0,
               79200.0,  73200.0,  70000.0,  68600.0,
              ...
               11300.0,  10000.0,   9970.0,   9100.0,   7000.0,   6670.0,
                5000.0,   4490.0,   3880.0,   3000.0],
             dtype='float64', length=29498)
```

As the wind speed values are `NaN` more often than not, I intended to interpolate considering the different pressure levels in order to have more wind speed values to work with.

The [docs of interpolate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) state that there's a method called "index" which interpolates considering the index-values, but the results don't make sense as compared to the initial values:

```
bla.interpolate(method="index", axis=0, limit=1, limit_direction="both")
100200.0     **2.00**
97600.0     10.40
91100.0      8.00
85000.0      **3.00**
82600.0      9.75
            ...  
6670.0       3.00
5000.0       **2.00**
4490.0       9.00
3880.0       5.00
3000.0       **9.00**
Length: 29498, dtype: float64
```

I marked the original values in boldface.
I'd rather expect something like when using "linear":

```
bla.interpolate(method="linear", axis=0, limit=1, limit_direction="both")
100200.0    **2.000000**
97600.0     2.333333
91100.0     2.666667
85000.0     **3.000000**
82600.0     4.600000
              ...   
6670.0      4.500000
5000.0      **2.000000**
4490.0      4.333333
3880.0      6.666667
3000.0      **9.000000**
```

Nevertheless, I'd like to use properly "index" as interpolation method, since this should be the most accurate considering the pressure levels for interpolation to mark the "distance" between each wind speed value.

By and large, I'd like to understand how the interpolation results using "index" with the pressure levels in it could become so counterintuitive, and how I could achieve them to be more sound.

Comment: `Length: 29498`. That's your issue. You've shown a small subset of those rows, likely somewhere in those 30,000 rows there's a non-null value with an index between 102K and 85K. Those values are considered during the interpolation. (look at `bla.sort_index()`)

Comment: Thanks, by virtue of your comment I realized that I needed to look at each subset of my multiindex-dataframe separately (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ALollz in the first comment underneath my question I came up where the issue lied:

It was just that my dataframe had 2 index levels, the outer being unique measuring timestamps, the inner being a standard range-index.
I should've looked just at each sub-set associated with the unique timestamps separately.
Within these subsets, interpolation makes sense and the results are being produced just right.

**Example:**

```
# Loop over all unique timestamps in the outermost index level
for timestamp in df.index.get_level_values(level=0).unique():
    # Extract the current subset
    df_subset = df.loc[timestamp, :]

    # Carry out interpolation on a column of interest
    df_subset["column of interest"] = df_subset[
        "column of interest"].interpolate(method="linear",
                                          axis=0,
                                          limit=1,
                                          limit_direction="both")
```